# dynamic loading of elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that displays loading on the screen, but when I have a loading within a loading there is a problem

try click button to "loading upload image" after "loading main".

I try use "> .webAppModal__loading" but my element is inside another element, I would need to get the closest element

that I managed to load the 2 loadings without having a conflict between one and the other.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://minecart.com.br/assets/js/jquery.min.js?v=2.0.64"></script>

    <style>
.webAppModal__loading{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    text-align: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

.webAppModal__loading img {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0;margin:0px;">
    <button onclick="showLoading('#main');">loading main</button>
    <button onclick="showLoading('#upload');">loading upload image</button>

    <div id="main" style="background: red;height:100vh;position:relative;">
        <div id="upload" style="background: blue;width:300px;height:300px;position:relative;">
            this upload image :D
        </div>

        <div>
            other content
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function fadeIn(el, duration = 300, callback = "") {
            $(el).fadeIn(duration, function() {
                if (swpanel.functions.is_function(callback)) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }

        function showLoading(element, time = 450) {
            let $element = (typeof element === "string") ?
                document.querySelector(element) :
                element;

            if ($element.querySelector(".webApp-shopDefaultModalLoading")) {
                fadeIn($element.querySelector(".webApp-shopDefaultModalLoading"), time);
            } else if ($element.querySelector(".webAppModal__loading")) {
                fadeIn($element.querySelector(".webAppModal__loading"), time);
            } else {
                let _div = document.createElement("div");
                let _image = document.createElement("img");

                _image.src = `https://minecart.com.br/assets/img/loading.gif`;

                _div.setAttribute("class", "webApp-shopDefaultModalLoading webAppModal__loading");
                _div.appendChild(_image);

                $element.appendChild(_div);

                showLoading(element);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, I added a name for each loading, to have a clear reference

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://minecart.com.br/assets/js/jquery.min.js?v=2.0.64"></script>

    <style>
.webAppModal__loading{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    text-align: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

.webAppModal__loading img {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0;margin:0px;">
    <button onclick="showLoading('main', '#main');">loading main</button>
    <button onclick="showLoading('upload', '#upload');">loading upload image</button>

    <div id="main" style="background: red;height:100vh;position:relative;">
        <div id="upload" style="background: blue;width:300px;height:300px;position:relative;">
            this upload image :D
        </div>

        <div>
            other content
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function fadeIn(el, duration = 300, callback = "") {
            $(el).fadeIn(duration);
        }

        function showLoading(name, element, time = 450) {
            if ($(`[loading="${name}"]`).length > 0) {
                fadeIn($(`[loading="${name}"]`).get()[0], time);
            } else {
                let _div = document.createElement("div");
                let _image = document.createElement("img");

                _image.src = `https://minecart.com.br/assets/img/loading.gif`;

                _div.setAttribute("loading", name);
                _div.setAttribute("class", "webApp-shopDefaultModalLoading webAppModal__loading");
                _div.appendChild(_image);

                const $element = (typeof element === "string") ?
                    document.querySelector(element) :
                    element;

                $element.appendChild(_div);

                showLoading(name, element);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).